# Find Sequence Words SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, search

I am using SQL Server 2008 and I need to search a full sentence in a `Words` table.

`Words`

```
ID          LineNum     WordText
----------- ----------- -----------
1           1           i
2           1           love
3           2           i
4           2           love
5           2           ice
6           3           i
7           3           love
8           3           dogs
9           3           too
```

If the sentence is 'i love dogs', the result in this case should be ID 6-8 only.

```
ID          LineNum     WordText
----------- ----------- ------------
6           3           i
7           3           love
8           3           dogs
```

Comment: what if the sequence occurs multiple times, do you want all matches? Do you want to compound multiple sequential spaces in the sentence?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
SELECT T1.linenum, 
       word = STUFF((
          SELECT ' ' + T2.wordtext
          FROM TableName T2
          WHERE T1.linenum = T2.linenum
          FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')
FROM TableName T1
GROUP BY T1.linenum
ORDER BY T1.linenum
```

Result:

```
LINENUM     WORD
----------------------------
1           i love
2           i love ice
3           I love dogs too
```

See result in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ed910/2).

**EDIT:**

For result as a list, this is the best I could come up with:

```
WITH CTE AS 
(SELECT T1.linenum
    , word = STUFF((
          SELECT ' ' + T2.wordtext
          FROM TableName T2
          WHERE T1.linenum = T2.linenum
          FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')
FROM TableName T1
GROUP BY T1.linenum)
SELECT T3.*
FROM CTE JOIN
TableName T3 ON CTE.linenum=T3.linenum
WHERE CTE.word LIKE '%I love dogs%'
```

Result:

```
ID  LINENUM WORDTEXT
6   3       I
7   3       love
8   3       dogs
9   3       too
```

Sample result in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c7f5e/4).

Answer (score 1):

*You need a splitter function for this. Read Jeff Moden's [article](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/) for one of the fastest splitter there is.*

First, you want to concatenate `WordText` with the same `LineNum` to produce the sentence and check if a the concatenated `WordText`s contains the `@sentence` parameter. Then you only get the `WordTexts` from the `Words` table that has the words in the `@sentence`.

```
DECLARE @sentence VARCHAR(8000) = 'i love dogs'
DECLARE @delimiter CHAR(1) = ' '

;WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT 
        w1.LineNum,
        Sentence = STUFF((
            SELECT ' ' + w2.WordText
            FROM Words w2
            WHERE w1.LineNum = w2.LineNum
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'), 
        1, 1, '')
    FROM Words w1
    GROUP BY w1.LineNum
)
SELECT w.*
FROM CTE c
INNER JOIN Words w
    ON w.LineNum = c.LineNum
INNER JOIN dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(@sentence, @delimiter) d
    ON d.Item = w.WordText
WHERE c.Sentence LIKE '%' + @sentence + '%'
ORDER BY w.ID
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/85b0a/1)

**RESULT**

```
ID          LineNum     WordText
----------- ----------- ----------
6           3           i
7           3           love
8           3           dogs
```

Comment: Heres a better comparison of string splitting option with TSQL http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings

Answer (score 0):

Here I am splitting the given word into column and stored into a table. And counting the words by using `count` with `partition by` and joining with the main table by matching the count of words of the given text.

I have used this answer for splitting the text into table column.

```
 declare @commavalue varchar(50)='I love dogs'
 declare @table1 table(id int identity(1,1), wordtext varchar(30))

 insert into @table1

 select q2.value from
 (
   SELECT cast('<x>'+replace(@commavalue,'','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml) 
   as Data
 ) q1 

 CROSS APPLY

 (
   SELECT x.value('.','varchar(100)') as value 
   FROM Data.nodes('x') as f(x)
 ) q2

declare @table table(id int identity(1,1), linenum int, wordtext varchar(30))

insert into @table values( 1, 'i' )
insert into @table values( 1, 'love')
insert into @table values( 2, 'i' )
insert into @table values( 2, 'love')
insert into @table values( 2, 'ice')
insert into @table values( 3, 'i')
insert into @table values( 3, 'love' )
insert into @table values( 3, 'dogs')
insert into @table values( 3, 'too' )

select t.* from
(
 select t1.linenum, 
 count(t1.wordtext) over(partition by t1.linenum order by t1.id) wordCount
 from @table t1  
 join @table1 t2 on t1.wordtext = t2.wordtext
)
 wc
 join @table t on wc.linenum = t.linenum
 join @table1 t1 on t.wordtext = t1.wordtext
where wordcount = (select count(1) from @table1)
```